How print Date as Date using ObjectMapper in Spring App?
I am using Spring XML App (not Spring Boot and can't move), when I used below code I am getting details value for Date, what I want to just print yyyy-MM-dd format.
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class MainDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Employee employee = Employee.builder().firstName("John").lastName("Doe").salary(10000L).joiningDate(LocalDate.now()).build();

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(employee);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Long salary;
    private LocalDate joiningDate;
}

Output -
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","salary":10000,"joiningDate":{"year":2024,"month":"MAY","dayOfMonth":28,"monthValue":5,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"},"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":149,"era":"CE","leapYear":true}}

I simply wants to print date as
2024-May-25

If you are using the Spring configured ObjectMapper you don't need to add anything. Use Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build() it will automatically register all modules and mappers you need and detects. Create it as a bean and inject it. If you are using regular Spring MVC setup and use @ResponseBody this will be done automatically. So generally all of your problems come from you trying to outsmart the configuration that is alrady done for you (and yes even in a plain Spring appplication).

Even if I didn't know about Jackson or Spring, your code would look very fishy because you're mixing the legacy class SimpleDateFormat (which shouldn't be used in new applications) with the new class java.time.LocalDate. Those two classes aren't meant to be used together.

I was able to solve the issue by adding below code
Employee employee = Employee.builder().firstName("John").lastName("Doe").salary(10000L).joiningDate(LocalDate.now()).build();

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(employee);
        System.out.println(json);

Result:
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","salary":10000,"joiningDate":"2024-05-28"}


Use Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build() instead of creating your own ObjectMapper. In fact register the result of that call as a bean and inject that into your class where you need it.

@M.Deinum - Can you pls show some code ?

I already showed you the code.

You are not using your SimpleDateFormat instance for anything. Which is good since that class was a notorious troublemaker now long outdated.
